# Remover elementos de un array que contengan texto que estan en otro array

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando eliminar elementos de un array que contengan texto de otro array, ejemplo:

```js
let arr1 = [
  'alparg','alpdo','alpen', 'es',
  'mx', 'pe', 'pkles', 'pklit'
];
    
let arrExclude = [ 'alp', 'pkl']
  
arr1.filter((lang) => {
    return !arrExclude.includes(lang);
});
```

Salida esperada:

[ 'es', 'mx', 'pe']

Salida que obtengo:

[ 'alparg', 'alpdo', 'alpen', 'es', 'mx', 'pe', 'pkles', 'pklit' ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `Array.prototype.includes` retorna `true` si existe en el Array un elemento *estrictamente igual* al argumento. La forma adecuada usando los métodos de `Array.prototype` sería esta:

```js
arr1.filter((lang) => {
    return !arrExclude.some((ex) => lang.includes(ex));
});
```

La función `Array.prototype.some` retorna `true` si al llamar el callback para cada uno de los elementos el valor de retorno es alguna vez verdadero (*truthy*).

Comment: Con la función Array.prototype.some obtuve lo esperado, muchas gracias por tú ayuda!

Comment: @LuisCalamaro si esta respuesta satisface tu pregunta recuerda marcala como aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa y para que no quede pendiente para siempre. En [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo, gracias.